# With React useState how do you access key values of an array returned from fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Using React, how do you access the key values, `phone_id` in this particular case, of an array returned from a fetch that is set using `useState`?

```
const [ contactData, setContactData ] = useState([]);
...fetch
setContactData(body)
```

Then if I `console.log(contactData)` this is the response:

```
ContactsForPhone: Array(1)
  0:
    Phone: {contact_id: 1, phone_id: "1234567890"}
    phone_id: "1234567890"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
contact_id: 1
first_name: "first"
last_name: "last"
```

When trying to display the data in the html of `return()`, `{contactData.first_name}` is accessible, but how do you access `phone_id`?

Initially attempted with `{contactData.ContactsForPhone[0].phone_id}`, but received the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Initially your `contactData` is an empty array so `contactData.ContactsForPhone` will be undefined ==> you got the error.
- You need to check before access ContactsForPhone[0]

```js
{contactData && contactData.ContactsForPhone && contactData.ContactsForPhone[0] ? contactData.ContactsForPhone[0].phone_id : ""}
```

More Info:
The data you get from api request is actually an object, after fetching it you call `setContactData(body)` that make `contactData` become an object. `contactData` actually store an object but you define it as an array initially, it makes you or people read the code confused.
==> Better to define it as `const [ contactData, setContactData ] = useState(null);` or `const [ contactData, setContactData ] = useState({});`

Answer (score 1):

With the reference of another expert answer by RIYAJ KHAN, I think a ternary operator can help at html side:

```
{ ( contactData && contactData.ContactsForPhone && contactData.ContactsForPhone.length > 0 )  ? contactData.ContactsForPhone[0].phone_id : ''}
```

Comment: I thought so too initially, but it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Ok let me verify

Comment: @ckingchris please  check again. As its a property (not index) so we need to use it as property(in quotes).

Comment: seems to give the same error; I wonder if the values need to be mapped before rendering in the JSX?

Comment: Can you access the phone_id value on the javascript side before returning to html? If not, fix that first

Comment: Yes, to simplify the problem, you can write a transformation function to flatten the contact data before returning. But remember you have to write another function before sending data back to API

Answer (score 1):

Initially before fetching data, `contactData` will be blank array.

So, there is no  such property `ContactsForPhone` will exist in the collection.

Better way to do this.

```
let phoneId;
if(contactData.ContactsForPhone.length > 0){ //add check for length check
     phoneId = contactData.ContactsForPhone[0].phone_id;
}
```

Comment: After setting call `setContactData(body)` the `contactData` is no longer an array, it will be an object instead, so there is no `length` attribute of `contactData `. Please check my comment for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To access phone_id, try this `{contactData.ContactsForPhone[0].phone_id}`.

phone_id is within an array (ContactsForPhone) and so first you need to access the array, then the index of that, then finally the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `contactData` is an object, from the structure you provided it looks like `ContactsForPhone` is an array. So you can try something like `contactData.ContactsForPhone[0].phone_id`